# python filter for html content

Tags: python

i need using ip address to get content
for example 
ip address = 157.123.22.11
i need get the organization value Zenith Data Systems

```
<td>

  Zenith Data Systems</td>

 </tr>

 <tr class="odd">

<th>Organization:</th>

   <td>

      Zenith Data Systems</td>

  </tr>

 </table>
```

i using urllib2 to get html content, the code from some friends like

```
 import urllib2
 import lxml.html as lh

 req = urllib2.Request("http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
 html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
 doc=lh.fromstring(html)
 print ''.join(doc.xpath('.//*[@class="odd"]')[-1].text_content().split())
```

but it shows import lxml.html as lh ImportError: No module named lxml.html.
So can you give me solution to print the organization name in website, directly get the website content without any new installation like install lxml, my Python is 2.4.3 version

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "without any new installation".  Is there a reason you can't just install lxml?  Your code seems to work okay, and gives me `Organization:ZenithDataSystems`.

Comment: i didn't know what is lxml.html? i need install lxml ?

Comment: `from lxml import html as lh`

Comment: @JesseSiu, you want get ip, only?

Comment: @JesseSiu: yes, it's a separate library, but one that's easy to install.  See [here](http://lxml.de/installation.html) for example.  @inspectorG4dget: I don't understand -- why would that work if `import lxml.html as lh` doesn't?

Comment: @DSM: try it out on py2.7. My solution works on my install of py2.7.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: that's strange.  Both work on mine.  Are you saying that `import lxml.html as lh` fails for you?

Comment: @DSM: I don't have an `lxml` install. But that's the behavior I get with `os.sys` and whole bunch of others. I figure the concept still applies

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: ah, I see.  That's not how `lxml` is set up, though.

Comment: @DSM: I have already install the lxml and it still has error. File "ext.py", line 2, in ?
    import lxml.html as lh
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 42, in ?
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: xmlMemDisplayLast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lxml is not a standard library, so you need to install it.

Install lxml via pip is better:

```
pip install lxml
```

Comment: Or use any of the methods described in [the installation docs](http://lxml.de/installation.html).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a class that inherits HTMLParser.HTMLParser. You will also need to implement the handle_starttag, handle_endtag and handle_data methods to parse string HTML.

Check the python docs for details: [HTMLParser class](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html)